# How to set expire time in cookies AngularJS (1.4)?

Tags: angularjs, session, cookies, angular-cookies, expired-cookies

**In case of user login I want to save the user data in cookies so that I can use that when the browser is closed and again open the website.** For adding cookies I am using angular-cookies.js which given by angular. (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies)

`angular.module("app", ['ngCookies']);` *(This is added)* 
`app.controller("xyzController", function ($cookieStore) {});` *(cookies is added into the controller)*

Inside the function when I am storing the cookies I am using this code: 
`var expireDate = new Date();
expireDate.setDate(expireDate.getDate() + 10);
$cookies.put('data-login-user',JSON.stringify($scope.loginuser),{'expires': expireDate});`

In this case the cookies is adding but it is going to session cookies. There is no expire time but according to the code I am passing 10days expire time which is not setting up in cookies.
**So how can i add expire time to cookies by using this library?**

[image]

The red mark cookies are the cookies which is pushed by this code by its going to session cookies

Comment: Could you provide us with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Your code is supposed to work just fine.

Comment: I have added the screenshot of the cookies when its getting stored.